# Cut a sequence into two homogeneous parts

Tags: algorithm, sequence

I would like to cut a sequence of classes into 2 parts, with each part as "homogeneous" as possible :

- A part should contains as few classes as possible
- it is better if the parts have similar lenght.

Exemple of results :

```
[A, A, A, A, A, B, B, B, B, B] -> [A, A, A, A, A] + [B, B, B, B, B]
[A, A, A, B, B, B, B, B, B, B] -> [A, A, A] + [B, B, B, B, B, B, B]
[A, B, B, B, B, A, A, A, A, A] -> [A, B, B, B, B] + [A, A, A, A, A]
[A, B, C, A, B, D, D, D, D, D] -> [A, B, C, A, B] + [D, D, D, D, D]
[A, A, B, B, C, C, C, D, D, D] -> [A, A, B, B] + [C, C, C, D, D, D]
[B, B, A, A, A, A, B, B, B, B] -> [B, B, A, A, A, A] + [B, B, B, B]
[A, A, A, B, B, B, B, C, B, B] -> [A, A, A] + [B, B, B, B, C, B, B]
```

I am not able to merge these criteria into a single score to determine the best cutting.
I tried formula based on [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) (try all possible cuttings, compute the entropy of both parts, and try to minimize the max/average) or criteria that maximize the frequency of each class (a part is better of it contains ~0% or ~100% of all occurences of a classes).

These methods doesn't take the order of the sequence into consideration. The results are OK, but there is still cases where each score method leads to "unnatural" results (part with one element + a okay-ish score for the rest of the sequence, ...)

Comment: You'll have to define what you consider "unnatural" in measurable terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two costs to minimise:

- Cost 1: The distance of the split from the center of the array
- Cost 2: The number of distinct items in the left group plus the number of distinct items in the right group. You can use a HashSet to efficiently keep a count of distinct values.

Now you have a choice to make: what is the relevant importance of these costs? Is the first cost more important than the second or vice versa? Also, should these costs be considered as linearly increasing, or do they grow with an increasing speed? The answer to these questions will give a clue on how to aggregate these two costs into one final cost.

For instance, you could say that a split that is 4 units away from the center is twice as bad as a split that is 2 units away; or you could say it is quadratic: the first split is 4 times worse than the second split. As you state that a split right after the first element is "unnatural", I guess you would prefer the quadratic (or even higher power) of the first cost.

The same can be done for the second cost.

### Examples

To illustrate, here is a case where you could argue where to split:

```
[A, B, C, C, C, C, C, C, B, C]
```

Which cut would be better?

```
[A, B] + [C, C, C, C, C, C, B, C]
```

or:

```
[A] + [B, C, C, C, C, C, C, B, C]
```

If the first cost is more important, then the first solution could be better, if the second cost is more important, then it will be the second solution.

If we consider the first solution better, then wonder how many *extra* A could be inserted at the start of the input before the decision to split at the first C would no longer be considered good?

If we consider the second solution better, then wonder how many *extra* C values could be inserted in the "C-block" until the decision would change (if ever)?

### Proposal

One possible formula is:

Cost = Cost<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + Cost<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>

Here is a JavaScript implementation showing the result for the examples you provided:

```js
function optimalSplit(a) {
    // Store a count of distinct elements at the right for each split
    let right = new Set;
    let rightSize = [];
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        right.add(a[i]); // only adds the value when not yet present
        rightSize[i] = right.size;
    }

    // Do the same for the left side, and calculate the final cost for each split
    let left = new Set;
    left.add(a[0]);
    let k; // the optimal index at which to split
    let minCost = Infinity;
    for (let i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        let cost = (a.length/2 - i)**2 + (left.size + rightSize[i])**2;
        if (cost < minCost) {
            minCost = cost;
            k = i;
        };
        left.add(a[i]);
    }
    return [a.slice(0, k), a.slice(k)];
}

// Examples
let testCases = [
    ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    ["A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
    ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"],
    ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"],
    ["B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B"]
];

for (let input of testCases) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(optimalSplit(input)));
}
```